# How to schedule web services responses?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I'm a bit new to web services, but I'm using *Axis2 with Java*.

My question is simple, is it possible to schedule a web service function to return **String data** every, say 10 minutes?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Your client can only receive an HTTP response in direct reply to its request.

Comment: It seems I have been approaching the whole concept from the wrong angle from the beginning anyway, but thanks for trying to clear up my mess.

Answer (score 3):

Having a webservice deliver something to you (push) is not possible, since it's an interface used for retrieving (pull) data.

Client side, you can build an application, either as a standalone application, using Thread.sleep, waiting for a given period of time, or you utilize JCron, Quartz or another scheduling API for querying at a given interval.

So, in summary, you cannot have a web service deliver "anything" at a given interval.